# How to use the gpio of the orange-pi zero in conjunction with gobot

Tags: go, gpio, orange-pi, gobot.io

For turning on led lights I want to access the GPIO of the orange-pi zero via [gobot](https://gobot.io/) I am using gobot since my server from which i want to do this is written in Go. However on the platforms section of gobot it does not mention the orange-pi platform. I already got the gpio working via [this](https://opi-gpio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library but it is written in Python.

I found an [issue](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gobot/issues/423) discussing the mapping of the device gpio but since I am new to the physical device scene i do not know how i would implement this into gobot

I have [this](http://www.orangepi.org/OrangePiZeroPlus/) version of the orange pi with the [following](http://linux-sunxi.org/Xunlong_Orange_Pi_Zero_Plus) pin configuration.

The sample code i found for enabling gpio on a raspberry pi is as follows:

```
    r := raspi.NewAdaptor()
    led := gpio.NewLedDriver(r, "7")

    work := func() {
        gobot.Every(1*time.Second, func() {
            led.Toggle()
        })
    }

    robot := gobot.NewRobot("blinkBot",
        []gobot.Connection{r},
        []gobot.Device{led},
        work,
    )

    robot.Start()
```

I think the number on this line is relevant for my question
`led := gpio.NewLedDriver(r, "7")`

My final question then is:

**How do i use the gpio via gobot on an orange pi zero plus?**

Comment: This is not an answer. But would you consider having two programs, the python program running as a daemon with an HTTP server for example to take commands from the Go program? I think that you won't find much support for orange-pi especially in Go.

Comment: @Seaskyways, thanks for the suggestion  I have thought of that possibility, I have also thought of the possibility of using CGO and a c library as that way i won't have to start another executable. It would be nice however to have one executable that handles everything.

Comment: CGo is a great choice too ! You can , as an option, build your program with go, compile it as a C library, and use it in python.